# Problems showing results in custom template .html.twig

Tags: 8, theming

I made a module that executes a query and shows the result in a page, the query is executed correctly, but the result is not shown in the template.

I know that the query is executed correctly because I used `var_dump()` to verify that.

This is the code in the controller.

```
public function ahcmembers() {

  $nums = array();
  $query = Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type', 'member')
    ->condition('field_member_type', 'number')
    ->execute();
  if (!empty($query)) {
    foreach ($query as $numId) {
      $num = Node::load($numId);
      $nums[] = $num;
    }
  }
  return array(
    '#theme'  => 'ahcmembers',
    '#titulo' => $this->t('Members'),
    '#nums'   => $nums,
  );
}
```

This is the code in the template:

```
<div>
{% if nums %}
    {% for n in nums %}
        <div>{{ n.get('title').value }}</div>
        <div>{{ n.get('field_member_type').value }}</div>  
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you calling `ahcmembers()`? Or is that supposed to be some `build()` function inside a controller or a block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.2.x) using code similar to the following one.

```php
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'ahcmembers' => [
      'template'  => 'ahcmembers',
      'variables' => [
        'nums' => [],
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Create a *ahcmembers.html.twig* template file inside MYMODULE/templates and clear the cache.

Comment: Thanks, your answer has been helpful, I'm trying, it still does not work but I think it's some mistake with parentheses and {}

Comment: `'template'` is not necessary when the template is called to the same as the theme.